# How to share a Facebook application post with friends

Tags: facebook

Bob, Mary and Jane are Facebook users. MyApp is a Facebook Application.

Bob and Mary are friends. Mary and Jane are friends. Bob and Jane *are not friends*.
Bob is a user of MyApp (installed, publish_stream).

MyApp publishes a post to Bob's stream, using the Graph API [Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post) (scroll to "Publishing").
Mary "likes" or "comments" on the post.

**Problem**: Jane cannot see Mary's "like" or "comment" (she would be able to see a "like" by Mary of Bob's status).

1. I cannot, for the life of me figure out how to create a Post that can be shared further. I tried changing the *privacy* field to *FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS* , *EVERYBODY*, etc.
2. Alternately, any suggestions on how to include or write a "share" *action* link would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that what you're trying to do is possible.